# How to import two different things called the same from different modules?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, wand

I have two modules, first one is PIL, and the second one is wand, which I import from PIL and wand something called Image, and there is conflict, how do I overcome this problem?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new('RGB', (1600,1600), (0,0,0)) 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

red = (255,0,0)
for x in range(0, 1600, 200):
    for y in range(0, 1600, 200):
        draw.rectangle(((0+x,0+y),(99+x,99+y)), red)
for x in range(100, 1600, 200):
    for y in range(100, 1600, 200):
        draw.rectangle(((0+x,0+y),(99+x,99+y)), red)


from wand.image import Image
img.swirl(degree =-90)

img
```

I have this error...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [9], in <cell line: 18>()
     14         draw.rectangle(((0+x,0+y),(99+x,99+y)), top)
     16 from wand.image import Image
---> 18 img.swirl(degree =-90)
     20 img

File /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:548, in Image.__getattr__(self, name)
    541     warnings.warn(
    542         "Image categories are deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 "
    543         "(2023-07-01). Use is_animated instead.",
    544         DeprecationWarning,
    545         stacklevel=2,
    546     )
    547     return self._category
--> 548 raise AttributeError(name)

AttributeError: swirl
```

**EDIT**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new('RGB', (1600,1600), (0,0,0)) 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

top = (255,0,0)

for x in range(0, 1600, 200):
    for y in range(0, 1600, 200):
        draw.rectangle(((0+x,0+y),(99+x,99+y)), top)
        
for x in range(100, 1600, 200):
    for y in range(100, 1600, 200):
        draw.rectangle(((0+x,0+y),(99+x,99+y)), top)

from wand.image import Image as ooo
        
with ooo(img) as img:
    img.swirl(degree =-90)

img
```

I tried like this but got this error...

```
TypeError: image must be a wand.image.Image instance, not <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=1600x1600 at 0x7FE681031600>
```

Comment: Importing wand's version of `Image` isn't going to magically transform your existing PIL `Image` into something that supports wand-specific methods.  Perhaps there's a way to transform one into the other - but the simplest solution would be to do everything with a wand `Image` from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use an alias as mhmtsrmn described:

```py
from wand.image import Image as <an_alias>
```

Or you can simply import modules and use full names:

```py
import PIL
import wand.image

img = PIL.Image.new('RGB', (1600,1600), (0,0,0)) 
draw = PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(img)

with wand.image.Image(filename='file.png') as wand_img:
   ...
```

This might also help clear misunderstanding around your issue: [`.swirl()` is a function on `wand.image.Image`](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.7/guide/fx.html#swirl), not on [`PIL.Image`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image). Since these are two separate classes, you cannot simply call `.swirl()` on an instance of `PIL.Image`.

Comment: Thanks! Full names are working, this is big help!

Answer (score 4):

```
from wand.image import Image as <an_alias>
```